# Fetch Https URL with AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This side says that it can support https through the code provided. However, the Appengine SDK complains that:

```
java.net.InetAddress is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

java.net.Socket is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment 

javax.net.ssl.SSLSession is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment
```

Comment: My point is how can we do "rest" calls from the appengine code?

Comment: well obviously, yes. urlfetch does a HTTP or HTTPS request, which is basically calling a given URL, and this is basically RESTful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See urlfetch (for both Java and Python): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/

> App Engine applications can communicate with other applications or
>   access other resources on the web by fetching URLs. An app can use the
>   URL Fetch service to issue **HTTP and HTTPS** requests and receive
>   responses. The URL Fetch service uses Google's network infrastructure
>   for efficiency and scaling purposes.

**Example:**

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

// ...
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/atom.xml");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // ...
            }
            reader.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // ...
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ...
        }
```

---

**About HTTP(S):**

> The URL to be fetched can use **any port number in the following ranges:
>   80-90, 440-450, 1024-65535**. If the port is not mentioned in the URL,
>   the port is implied by the scheme: http://... is port 80, https://...
>   is port 443.

Answer (score 1):

You must use URL Fetch API.

Here's the reference. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview#Secure_Connections_and_HTTPS